# Alternatives to Microsoft Word *only*

Tags: microsoft-word, word-processing

I'm aware of Open Office but it seems like overkill because all I need is a replacement to MS Word. I don't need any of the other programs like Excel and the rest.

A friend told me about AbiWord which I downloaded but it turned out to be less than 8MB. I haven't installed it yet, but does anyone know about it or know if it's a full-featured enough program? I'm looking for something that's full-featured and that has a similar capability level as MS Word.

P.S. I've just recently formatted my computer, so really want to avoid downloading a whole bunch of software off the web just to try each one out. Thought I'd ask here for some community opinion.

Comment: Why don't you just install the word processor component? I would have thought that there was an options page on the install.

Comment: On Open Office? I didn't think of that, but the other thing about open office is I think you have to save as .odt or something like that which can't be read unless someone downloads a reader. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can `Save As` most compatible file types. Check it out.

Comment: @dan: you can export to Word format from OpenOffice.

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this question for you.  What you consider full-featured, and what someone else does can differ markedly.  I think the only way to answer is for you to define the features you need and compare them to - or try - the candidate program(s).  And as long as the primary application meets your needs, what is the downside to a suite, but disk space?  The upside is more to choose from.  I'd also point out the greater compatibility of the open

Comment: ...suites with documents in competing formats.  More esoteric features might not work identically, but the same is true between different versions of Word.

Comment: Btw. is installing AbiWord and trying it out is really so much trouble than it is better to ask and rely on opinions of the others?

Comment: For comparison, if you install all the export options (Select at install), AbiWord can save in its format (.abw/.abw.gz) and also MS Word (both .doc and .docx), HTML (.html), multipart HTML (.mht), RichText (.rtf), Plain Text (.txt), Portable Document (.pdf), PostScript (.ps), DocBook (.db/.xml), Outlook Express (.eml), KWord (.kwd), XSL-FO (.fo), PalmDoc (.pdf), MIF (.mif), LaTeX (.tex, .ltx), Passepartout (.xml2ps), Applix (.aw), S5 (.s5), ISCII (.isc), Open(Office) Document (.odt and .swx), WML (.wml) and Newsgroup formatted text (.nwl). I prefer AbiWord over OOo, but LaTeX to either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open Office can be cut down to purely the Writer at installation time and will save as the following:

[image]